# How to create a file in a directory in java?

Tags: java, file-io

If I want to create a file in `C:/a/b/test.txt`, can I do something like:

```
File f = new File("C:/a/b/test.txt");
```

Also, I want to use `FileOutputStream` to create the file. So how would I do it? For some reason the file doesn't get created in the right directory.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

The best way to do it is:

```
String path = "C:" + File.separator + "hello" + File.separator + "hi.txt";
// Use relative path for Unix systems
File f = new File(path);

f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Won't work for Linux because there is no such thing as "C:" in unix systems.

Comment: Using `new File("/a/b/test.txt")` works for both systems. On Windows, it will be written to the same disk as where JVM runs.

Comment: `f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); f.createNewFile();`

Comment: Don't forget to check the called method (mkdirs and createNewFile) calls for errors

Comment: if(!file.exists()) f.createNewFile();

Answer (score 53):

You need to ensure that the parent directories exist before writing. You can do this by [`File#mkdirs()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).

```
File f = new File("C:/a/b/test.txt");
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
// ...
```

Answer (score 48):

## NIO.2

With [NIO.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29#JDK_7_and_NIO.2) in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html), you can use [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html), and [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CreateFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/foo/bar.txt");

        Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());

        try {
            Files.createFile(path);
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
            System.err.println("already exists: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use:

```
File f = new File("C:\\a\\b\\test.txt");
f.mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
```

Notice I changed the forward slashes to double back slashes for paths in Windows File System. This will create an empty file on the given path.

Comment: On Windows, both \\ and / are valid. The `createNewFile()` is by the way unnecessary when you write to it with `FileOutputStream` anyway.

Comment: @Eric Noted and Corrected, Thank you.

Comment: This created a directory called test.txt instead of file.

Answer (score 4):

```
String path = "C:"+File.separator+"hello";
String fname= path+File.separator+"abc.txt";
    File f = new File(path);
    File f1 = new File(fname);

    f.mkdirs() ;
    try {
        f1.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This should create a new file inside a directory

Answer (score 2):

A better and simpler way to do that :

```
File f = new File("C:/a/b/test.txt");
if(!f.exists()){
   f.createNewFile();
}
```

[Source](http://tutoref.com/how-to-create-directories-in-java/)

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, many of the answers don't give complete working code. Here it is:

```
public static void createFile(String fullPath) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fullPath);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    file.createNewFile();
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    String path = "C:/donkey/bray.txt";
    createFile(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create New File in Specified Path**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CreateNewFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("d:/sampleFile.txt");
            if(file.createNewFile())
                System.out.println("File creation successfull");
            else
                System.out.println("Error while creating File, file already exists in specified path");
        }
        catch(IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Program Output:**

File creation successfull

Answer (score 1):

To create a file and write some string there:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("Path to your file"));
bufferedWriter.write("Some string"); // to write some data
// bufferedWriter.write("");         // for empty file
bufferedWriter.close();
```

This works for Mac and PC.

Answer (score 0):

For using the FileOutputStream try this :

```
public class Main01{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);
        p.println("George.........");
        p.println("Alain..........");
        p.println("Gerard.........");
        p.close();
        f.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write to the file via file output stream, the file will be created automatically. but make sure all necessary directories ( folders) are created.

```
    String absolutePath = ...
    try{
       File file = new File(absolutePath);
       file.mkdirs() ;
       //all parent folders are created
       //now the file will be created when you start writing to it via FileOutputStream.
      }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error : "+ e.getmessage());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was here tackling this same problem and I finally solved it.

The goal is to create a file (example a .txt file) within a folder.

Things you'll need:

1. Folder name
2. 

Instead of this:

```java
File f = new File("C:/a/b/test.txt");
```

Try

```java
//get the file's absolute path. You could input it yourself
// but I think it is better to have a function to handle
// system rules on how to format the path string

String myFolder = "b";
String myFile = "test.txt";
String folderPath = myFolder.getAbsolutePath(); //will get the entire path for you

String pathToFile = folderPath + File.separator + myFile;

// this will probably throw a exception, you want to make sure you handle it
try {
    File newFile = new File(pathToFile);
    if (newFile.createNewFile()) {    
         System.out.println("bwahahah success");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("file creation failed");
    }
}catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());   // you will need to print the message in order to get some insight on what the problem is.
}

// you can also add a throw if within the if statement with other checks in order to know where the error is coming from, but to keep it short this is the gist of it.

// Really hope this will assist anyone that stumbles upon this same issue.
```

Other resources for further reading: [everything on java paths & files](https://www.happycoders.eu/java/how-to-construct-file-and-directory-names-with-file-path-paths/)

Please comment if there is anything I might also overlook, lemme absorb some of that knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Just joining some answers together.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileTargetLocation = "C:\\testing\\";
        String fileNameAndExtension = "test.txt";

        boolean fileCreated = createFile(fileTargetLocation, fileNameAndExtension);
        if (fileCreated) {
            String stringForFile = "This is some test text to write into the file.";
            writeIntoFile(fileTargetLocation, fileNameAndExtension, stringForFile);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to create a file at the given location, with the given file name and desired extension.
     *
     * @param fullPath             full path to folder in which the file needs to be created, example: C:\testing\
     *                             (ending with a foreword slash)
     * @param fileNameAndExtension file name and desired extension. Example: environment.properties, test.txt
     * @return successful file creation boolean
     */
    public static boolean createFile(String fullPath, String fileNameAndExtension) {
        try {
            return new File(fullPath + fileNameAndExtension).createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to write into the given file.
     *
     * @param fullPath             full path to folder in which the file needs to be created, example: C:\testing\
     *                             (ending with a foreword slash)
     * @param fileNameAndExtension file name and extension. Example: environment.properties, test.txt
     * @param whatToWriteToFile    string to write to the file
     */
    public static void writeIntoFile(String fullPath, String fileNameAndExtension, String whatToWriteToFile) {
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(fullPath + fileNameAndExtension))) {
            bufferedWriter.write(whatToWriteToFile);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```