# Java - create file and dir

Tags: java

Assume `final String fname = "/dir1/dir2/fname.ext"`. I do not wish to parse the string recursively in order to create the directories if they do not exist, and only then write to a file. I wish to use the given string, `fname`, for creating the directories and file if each of which does not exist.

Comment: Perfect, now we know what you like to do... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
File myFile = new File("/dir1/dir2/fname.ext");
myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
// do your writing being sure the parent directories exist.
```

Comment: Please correct to `myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()` so I could mark your post as an answer; and... thank you.

Comment: @MrRoth I think it was long corrected before you post your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mkdirs to create the path.

```
File f = new File("/dir1/dir2/fname.ext");
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

And then work on the file itself.