# Program Not Creating File. What is Wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have tried creating a file, using the code below:

```
import java.io.File;

public class DeleteEvidence {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File evidence = new File("cookedBooks.txt");
```

However, the file `cookedBooks.txt` does not exist anywhere on my computer. I'm pretty new to this, so I'm having problems understanding other threads about similar problems.

Comment: You question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file in a directory in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have successfully created an instance of the class `File`, which is very different from creating actual files in your hard drive.

Instances of the `File` class are used to refer to files on the disk. You can use them to many things, for instance:

- check if files or directories exist;
- create/delete/rename files or directories; and
- open "streams" to write data into the files.

To create a file in your hard disk and write some data to it, you could use, for instance, `FileOutputStream`.

```
public class AnExample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    final File file = new File("file.dat");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(fos)) {
      out.writeInt(42);
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `fos` in an instance of `FileOutputStream`, which is an `OutputStream` that writes all bytes written to it to an underlying file on disk.

Then, I create an instance of `DataOutputStream` around that `FileOutputStream`: this way, we can write more complex data types than bytes and byte arrays (which is your only possibility using the `FileOutputStream` directly).

Finally, four bytes of data are written to the file: the four bytes representing the integer `42`. Note that, if you open this file on a text editor, you will see garbage, since the code above did not write the characters '4' and '2'.

Another possibility would have been to use an `OutputStreamWriter`, which would give you an instance of `Writer` that can be used to write text (non-binary) files:

```
public class AnExample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    final File file = new File("file.txt");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
         OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
      out.write("You can read this with a text editor.");
    }
  }
}
```

Here, you can open the file `file.txt` on a text editor and read the message written to it.

Comment: Or `File#createNewFile` ;)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think I understand what you're saying. I'm just taking myself through Java For Dummies right now so I'm pretty bad at all of this.

Comment: :) keep going, things will become more and more clear the more you read and practice! Be sure to check the JavaDocs all the time. I'd suggest you to open it right now and read the description of the classes `FileOutputStream` and `File`. Maybe also you could check `DataOutputStream`, `Writer` and `OutputStreamWriter`! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 2):

```
File evidence = new File(path);
evidence.mkdirs(); 
evidence.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

`File` is an abstract concept of a file which does not have to exist.  Simply creating a `File` object does not actually create a physical object.

You can do this in (at least) two ways.

1. Write something to the file (reference by the abstract `File` object)
2. Calling [`File#createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)

You can also create temporary files using [`File#createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) but I don't think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have only created an object which can represent a file. This is just in memory though. If you want to access the file you must us ea `FileInputStream` or a `FileOutputStream`. Then it will also be created on the drive (in case of the outputstream).

```
 FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File(oFileName));
 fo.write("test".getBytes());
 fo.close();
```

Comment: Or `File#createNewFile` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is just ur creating file object by using this object u need to call one method i.e createFile() method..

So use evidence.createNewFile(); if you are creating just file.
else if u want to create file in any specific location then specify your file name 
i.e File evidence=new File("path");
In this case if ur specifying any directoty

Answer (score 0):

```
String path="abc.txt";
File file = new File(path);
if (file.createNewFile()) {
    System.out.println("File is created");
}
else {
    System.out.println("File is  already   created");
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
string ab="Hello";
fw.write(ab);
fw.write(summary);
fw.close();
```