# How to create a Path and a File that does not Exist in Java

Tags: java, nio

This is the problem I have: If part or all of the path does not already exist, the server should create additional directories as necessary in the hierarchy and then create a new file as above.

```
Files.createDirectories(path);
```

That's what I am currently using, but it does not create the end file. For example is the path="/hello/test.html" it will create a directory called "hello" and one called "test.html", I want the test.html to be a file. How can I do that?

Comment: Post the actual code that you're using so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java

Comment: Yes, see what @Matt has pointed to, but also I've found that Java works with forward-slash `/` separators on every system I've tried - Unix, Mac, Windows, even VMS where paths look like `volName:[topdir.subdir.otherdir]filename.txt`

Comment: Thanks mate, I just realised that createDirectories only creates directories not files....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did to solve this "problem" or misuse of the libraries.

```
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
Files.createFile(path);
```

The first line will get the parent directory, so lets say this is what I want to create "/a/b/c/hello.txt", the parent directory will be "/a/b/c/".

The second like will create the file within that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29)? `createDirectories` only creates... directories. If you're intent on using `Files.createDirectories`, parse off the file name, call `createDirectories` passing only the path portion, then create a new file passing the entire path. Otherwise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java) is a better approach.

```
Files.createDirectories(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1));
File yourFile = new File(path);
```

Comment: See my comment in @helloworld's answer - don't parse paths yourself, there are already methods for that.

Comment: As I said in the answer, "If you're intent on using Files.createDirectories... Otherwise..."

Answer (score 0):

1. you can parse the 'path' variable to isolate the file and the directory using delimiter as '/', and do `File file = new File(parsedPath);` This would work only when you know that you ALWAYS pass the file name at the end of it.
2. If you know when you are a) creating a directory b) creating a directory and file, you can pass the boolean variable that would describe if file needs to be created or not.

Comment: Better to use `File.separator` instead of hard-coding the '/'.

Comment: You're right, my intention was let user to get head started with the approach at least and then can better enhance it.

Comment: You don't have to parse first, you can just do `file = new File(somepath)` because File represents a path _and_ file that _could_ (but doesn't necessarily) exist. Then use `file.getCanonicalPath()` to get _only_ the path part of it with all things like "foo/../bar" already resolved. Then call createDirectories on _that_.

Comment: @helloworld If that's the case then why mention the delimiter at all? Just admit your mistake instead of rationalizing it.