# Creating a File in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse,I wanted to create a new File in  my Web Project .

My Eclipse Location is

```
Path:"H:\\eclipse\\New folder\\Testing_Project\\WebContent\\";
File:1.jsp(New File to be created)

File create=new File(Path,File);
create.createNewFile();
```

But it is saying that File is not created .It is saying the error as
"(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"

Is there any way i can create a File in Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Comment: @KumarSaurabh i tried those things ,but its not working ,i hope there should be some handling with Eclipse

Comment: have you tried java's `java.nio.file.Files` to create a new file?

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan no i have not tried it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this piece of snippet.

```
try {

      File file = new File("H:\\eclipse\\New folder\\Testing_Project\\WebContent\\");

      if (file.createNewFile()){
        System.out.println("File is created!");
      }else{
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: i wanted to create  a file named "1.jsp" .How to create with that  Name

Comment: `File file = new File("H:\\eclipse\\New Folder\\Testing_Project\\WebContent\\1.jsp");`
I think :)

Btw try to search first time, before you ask - look on posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java] or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java