# Create file if it doesn't exist in Groovy

Tags: file-io, groovy

I have a Groovy script where I am downloading a file from a url to my local machine like so..

```
URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/pszAeGh.png")
HttpURLConnection urlConn =  url.openConnection()
File pic = new File('/Users/me/Downloads', 'myimage.jpg')
pic.append(urlConn.getInputStream())
```

If the 'myimage.jpg' doesn't exist in the Downloads folder, I want the script to create it. How can I specify that? Right now the 3rd line gives

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/me/Downloads/myimage.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

Some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java) for Java have suggested using the createNewFile method but Groovy is failing even when it tries to create the file.

Comment: You have `/Users/me/Downloads` in the code, but `/Users/Downloads/me` in the error message...  Which is it?

Comment: I am sorry, it should be /Users/me/Downloads in both cases, I will fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
new File('/Users/me/Downloads', 'myImage.gif').withOutputStream { os ->
    os << new URL("http://i.imgur.com/pszAeGh.png").openStream()
}
```

Assuming `/Users/me/Downloads` exists