# java.io.FileNotFoundException:(Access is denied) convert byte array to image file

Tags: java, image, file, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I have a byte array, i want to create an image file(bmp file) of byte array. I create an images folder in src (my path is src/images/test.bmp). my code is in below, in

> OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

i get error. what is my problem? How can i solve this?

```
public static void saveImage() {
    String s="........................";
    byte[] dataCustImg = Base64.decode(s.getBytes());

    File file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
    file.mkdirs();
    try {
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        stream.write(dataCustImg);
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \images\test.bmp (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I can solve  my problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java link. but now i want to know how can solve my code with @EJP answer. I mean how create file and assign to fileoutputStream parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
```

OK.

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Redundant. Remove. `new FileOutputStream()` will create a new file.

```
file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
```

Redundant. Remove. It already is a `File` with this name.

```
file.mkdirs();
```

The problem is here. Change to

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

You are creating a *directory* called `"/images/test.bmp"`, rather than just ensuring that `"/images"` exists. This will cause `new FileOutputStream()` to fail with an access permission, as you can't overwrite a directory with a file.

```
try {
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Now carry on. Note that you will first have to delete the directory `"/images/test.bmp"`, manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when i have images folder in src path, now i want to save test.bmp in images folder, i should create file with File file=new File("/images/"), this is true? if yes how can save in test.bmp?how can set this in fileoutputstream? Sorry if my English is bad

Comment: please answer to my questions. Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need to do anything other that what I've stated above. I didn't say anything about `new File("/images")`. I don't know where you got that from, or what part of my answer you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here when you are calling mkdir then it is creating test.bmp as a directory not as a file, SO you have to first create directory and then you can create file. see the below code.

```
        File dir = new File("/images/");
        dir.mkdirs();
        file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
        file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: The `createNewFile()` call is redundant. `new FileOutputStream()` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is that you actually create a **directory** with the path `/images/test.bmp`

```
file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
file.mkdirs();
```

and later you want to open a **file**

```
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

If you want to ensure that the directory `/images` exist before you create the file you should use

```
File dir = new File("/images/");
dir.mkdirs();
```

The explicit delete before writing to the file isn't necessary, as the file would be overwritten by default.

Find a small working snippet below.

```
// create the directory if not exist
File dir = new File("/images/");
dir.mkdirs();
// create a new file or overwrite an existing one
File file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    os.write((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void saveImage() {
    String s="........................";
    byte[] dataCustImg = Base64.decode(s.getBytes());

    File file = new File("/images/test.bmp");
    if(!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
      file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    if(!file.exists()) {
      try {
        file.createNewFile();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    // because stream.write(dataCustImg) will overwrite the file if the file has already existed.
    try {
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        stream.write(dataCustImg);
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Fahim， I have edit the code above and tested it. It works in my computer. Suggest to use File.separator instead of "/" and "\".

Comment: The `exists()/createNewFile()` block is a complete and utter waste of time. The operating system has to do exactly that when `new FileOutputStream()` is called. You're forcing it to do it all twice. The existence check on the parent directory is pointless and wasteful as well, as `mkdirs()` already does it inside the OS.

Comment: @EJP  Now, I see. Thank you!