# Is using the File class in Java how you create a file?

Tags: java, file, io, file-handling

I need some serious help with concepts. I have been given background context on the class, specifically this:

[image]

I just need to understand the purpose of this class? Can I create a text file (or any other type of file) with its constructors? Is this just for handling files, if so, what does that mean?

Any help whatsoever will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: have you looked at it's documentation? have you checked any source of information (book, google, official documentation) ?

Comment: Have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java

Comment: No: a `File` is more like a representation of a path, like `/foo/bar/something.txt`. That may or may not exist (and you can check that using the `File.exists()` method. You can create the file using something like a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter`, which have constructors that take that `File` as a parameter, and will write to a file at the represented path (if it can).

Comment: And note that `File` is largely superseded by the [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file in a directory in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `java.io.File` to create a file on the file system:

```
File myFile = new File("myFile.txt");
myFile.createNewFile();
```

Note that invoking the constructor won't create the file on the file system.  To create an empty file, the `createNewFile()` method has to be invoked.

The `File` simply represents a abstraction of the file location, not the file itself. It comes with operations on the file identified by the path: `exists()`, `delete()`, `length()`, etc.

What you probably want is to use the classes that allow you to *write* content to a file:

- If you are to write text, you should use the `Writer` interface.
- If you are to write binary content, you should use the `OutputStream` interface.

The classes `FileWriter` and `FileOutputStream` are, respectively, the ones that link the `File` and `Writer/OutputStream` concepts together.  Those classes create the file on the file-system for you.

```
    FileWriter myFileWriter = null;
    File myFile = new File("myFile.txt");
    try {
        // file is created on the file-system here
        myFileWriter = new FileWriter(myFile);

        myFileWriter.write("hello");
    } finally {
        if (myFileWriter != null) {
            myFileWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file using the [File.createNewFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) method, or, if you are using Java 7 or newer, using the newer [Files.createFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) method.

The difference between the old File and the new Path classes is that the former mixed a reference to a path to a file on the filsystem and operations you can do on it, and the latter is just representing the path itself but allows you to query it and analyze its structure.