# Java create multiple new files

Tags: java, file, qr-code

I read this question here [How to create a file in a directory in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java)

I have a method that creates a QR Code. The method is called several times, depends on user input.

This is a code snippet:

```
String filePath = "/Users/Test/qrCODE.png";
int size = 250;
//tbd
String fileType = "png";
File myFile = new File(filePath);
```

The problem: If the user types "2" then this method will be triggered twice. 
As a result, the first qrCODE.png file will be replaced with the second qrCODE.png, so the first one is lost.

How can I generate more than one qr code with different names, like qrCODE.png and qrCODE(2).png

My idea:

```
if (!myFile.exists()) {
    try {
        myFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any tips?

**EDIT: I solved it by using a for loop and incrementing the number in the filename in every loop step.**

Comment: Why not testing the presence of the file before saving it, and if it exists recursively try with filename+(2) ?

Comment: `File.createTempFile("qrCODE", ".png", new File("/Users/Test"));`

Comment: Maybe use the timestamp in the file name: `System.currentMillis()` or use a `UUID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of solving the problem is a good one. My advice is to break up the `filePath` variable into a few variables in order to manipulate the file name easier. You can then introduce a `fileCounter` variable that will store the number of files created and use that variable to manipulate the name of the file.

```
int fileCounter = 1;
String basePath = "/Users/Test/";
String fileName = "qrCODE";
String fileType = ".png";

String filePath = basePath + fileName + fileType;
File myFile = new File(filePath);
```

You can then check if the file exists and if it does you just give a new value to the `filePath` variable and then create the new file

```
if(myFile.exists()){
    filePath = basePath + fileName + "(" + ++fileCounter + ")" + fileType;
    myFile = new File(filePath);
}
createFile(myFile);
```

And you're done!

Answer (score 3):

You can create more files eg. like follows

```
int totalCount = 0; //userinput

String filePath = "/Users/Test/";
String fileName= "qrCODE";
String fileType = "png";

for(int counter = 0; counter < totalCount; counter++){
    int size = 250;
    //tbd
    File myFile = new File(filePath+fileName+counter+"."+fileType);
    /*
       will result into files qrCODE0.png, qrCODE1.png, etc.. 
        created at the given location
    */
}
```

Btw to add check if file exists is also good point.

```
{...}
 if(!myFile.exists()){
    //file creation
    myFile.createNewFile()
 }else{
   //file already exists
 } 
{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `/Users/Test` direcroty before create file.

```
String dir = "/Users/Test";
String pngFileName = "qrCode";

long count = Files.list(Paths.get(dir))      // get all files from dir
    .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(pngFileName))   // check how many starts with "qrCode"
    .count();

pngFileName = pngFileName + "(" + count + ")";
```